# Qiskit visualizations module not installed but qiskit package installed. Why?

Tags: qiskit

I am trying to set up my qiskit environment but I seem to have run in trouble that I have no idea how to solve. I have installed the qiskit packages as can be seen by running `pip list`:

[image]

however whenever I try to import `qiskit.visualization` an error occurs:

[image]

and I don't understand why since it was suppose to be installed as `qiskit` module is installed. Any idea where this error comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running a very old version of qiskit, I would recommending updating and this error should go away. You can do this by running `pip install qiskit --upgrade`

Comment: Please see the edit. That was in fact the error, but as usual, another has come up

Comment: Hi! Please remove the edit and ask it as a separate question as it is unrelated to the original question :)

Comment: Will do, thank you. https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/10088/5620