# Why doesn't qiskit appear in "help("modules")" even though it is installed in python environment?

Tags: qiskit

I have updated qiskit to the newest version using `pip install qiskit --upgrade` and all was done successfully, and when I write `pip list` on the command line I get:

[image]

As I should. But then I run `help("modules")` on a jupyter notebook and get:

[image]

which I don't understand why are there no other modules. And obviously `import qiskit` throws an error as well. Any idea how to solve this?

PS: This is a follow-up from [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/10086/qiskit-visualizations-module-not-installed-but-qiskit-package-installed-why)

Comment: Are you using any virtual envs? This sounds like it is probably an issue with your Python path

Comment: yes, I created a virtual environment for qiskit

Comment: Did you install qiskit into the virtual environment you are running the notebook from?

Comment: how can I verify that?

Comment: I am not an expert in conda I am afraid, but this looks like it might be able to help https://docs.anaconda.com/ae-notebooks/user-guide/adv-tasks/work-with-environments/#using-your-conda-environment-in-a-notebook

Comment: you are most probably running a different python distribution/environment on the notebook. If you use conda, see e.g. [this page](https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084). More generally, make sure to start jupyter from the terminal from the same environment you installed qiskit in. This question isn't really about qiskit, only about how to use python packages

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with qiskit

Comment: Yes, that was the problem and I managed to solve it directly with the anaconda navigator.

Comment: I agree. But I won't delete it since someone may have the same problem

Answer (score -2):

A workaround to fix this is to manually add the qiskit install location to your python path in the notebook. You can find the path by running `pip show qiskit` in a terminal, which will return a field called `Location`. In the notebook then add the following lines

```
import sys
sys.path.append('the location')
```

Comment: you really shouldn't have to do this. If you installed the package correctly, it will be found. Changing the path manually like this to point to a package installed into another distribution is a great way to mess things up (unless you downloaded the package manually rather than with a package manager).

Comment: But is there any other answer to the question? No. So why the two -1 votes and nasty comment.